# How to use logs with AppDynamics adrum

Tags: vue.js, appdynamics

I'm injecting the adrum script `cdn.appdynamics.com/adrum/adrum-21.2.0.3385.js` in my Vue application to collect data about it.

It's working correctly, but I don't see any functionality to send specific logs to AppDynamics.

I'd like to have, in my typescripts files, some kind of function that I could use to send string logs and being able to read them within AppDynamics. Is that possible? In that case, where should I look for those logs in AppDynamics?

Answer (score 1):

Try sending it as custom user data, but a size limit is associated (of 2048 characters). It works for XHRs, Base pages, iframes, and Virtual pages. Data can be seen in the Controller UI under both Analytics and Browser Snapshots.

Documentation: https://docs.appdynamics.com/appd/22.x/latest/en/end-user-monitoring/browser-monitoring/browser-real-user-monitoring/configure-the-javascript-agent/add-custom-user-data-to-a-page-browser-snapshot